Geometry Nodes grow a premade branching curve in parallel
There is a branching curve made manually. With geometry nodes, how can it grow so that every time it splits, the growth is continuing parallel?
The arrows show the desired growing direction.


tbh that makes less sense to me, because it is much more complicated to make it growth (especially interpreting that old geometry) instead of making it from start on in GN. Is there a special need why you wanna do that? Maybe you should tell us more about your end goal, e.g. i wanna make a lightning between two points

parallel to what? Please sketch how you imagine it to look after a few iterations...

the end goal would be, that there is a predefined shape, which grows out from the lowest point. what i mean by parallel (and maybe its a poor choice of word) that every time the growth arrives to a point where the shape splits, the growth is continuing on both ways.

@hypotenuse aaah, so the shape you show is the desired end of animation and you want it to grow starting from nothing, correct? Could you maybe draw arrows how it's supposed to grow? I guess you want it to start at origin? Otherwise you would have to somehow communicate to geonodes the starting point...

thanks I added arrows to the image.

The simplest algorithm is this:



wow nice! thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge
